# Как включить обратный поиск (Inverse and Forward Search) в связке vim + vim-latex (latex-suite) + zathura?

Tags: vim, latex

Я нашёл уже много информации по этому поводу, но так и не смог добиться результата. Различных вариантов пользователи пишут много, а, так как результат нулевой, пробовать новые более не хочу. Может быть ты, опытный пользователь, знаешь правильный ответ на этот вопрос и сможешь мне помочь?

На официальном сайте [Latex-Suite](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/latex-viewing.html) написано, что необходимо сделать --- я попробовал, и не получилось. Различные варианты из этих ваших интернетов пробовал --- не получилось. Может быть я где-то допускаю несерьёзную ошибку, ведь инструкция везде не то, чтобы сложная.

Надеюсь на вашу помощь, спасибо!